# Como importar bibliotecas no unity 3d

Tags: unity3d, biblioteca, import

Então, estou com um projeto de unity 3d, onde nele preciso ajustar alguns problemas, sou completamente novo no unity...

Clonei o projeto no git. Porém lá havia um git ignore, na qual essas pastas e arquivos estavam inclusos:

Builds

*.apk

*.unitypackage

Assets/Editor/ImageEffects/

Assets/Standard Assets/

Assets/Editor/ImageEffects.meta

Assets/Standard Assets.meta

Numbergame/Library/assetDatabase3

Gostaria de saber se em alguma dessas pastas será necessário obter o conteúdo novamente dela... ou se em alguma delas mencionava bibliotecas da qual precisarei baixar para recolocar no projeto

Se sim, por favor me expliquem como posso baixar as dependências de um projeto unity

Answer (score 0):

Todas as dependencias que foram ultilizadas no projetos estarão listadas no documento manifest.json dentro da pasta Packages na raiz do projeto. A unity vai baixar essas dependendencias caso não estejam baixadas para dentro da pasta Library automaticamente quando você abrir o projeto. 
Se você quiser baixar pacotes adicionais va em window Package Manager.

[image]

Existem ainda sdks que podem ser baixados externamente, Managed plug-ins e Native plug-ins que também podem ser baixados ou criados.

De uma maneira geral Maneged plugins são bibliotecas criadas em c# e native plugin são bibliotecas criadas em outras linguagens geralmente feitas para acessar funções nativas de algum dispositivo.